# ImageViews and Buttons Android Apps

Tags: android, button, imageview, tablelayout

I'm trying to build an android application and I've created a screen with a table layout and added to the first table row an image view and two large texts, to the second row I've added one button.
When I change the text of the button it automatically changes the size of the image view above to match the size of the button.

Here is the code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ChildInfoActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/child_info_image_descreption" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childInfoNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_text_view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childInfoHasArrivedTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/has_arrived_text_view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/more_info_button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because when using `TableLayout`, each `TableRow` will have same size for each same column. Since the `ImageView` and `Button` are both on column 0, everything that affects `Button`'s width will also affect `ImageView`'s width.

If you permit the `Button` to span over many columns, add `android:layout_span="2"` to the `Button`. Else, use different layout, such as `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons have 
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. If you set 
`android:layout_width="100dp"` 
then your width won't be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Because your row item, which holds imageView and textViews, has "wrap_content" value as height. So probably when your texts' heights getting bigger than your imageviews it increases its parent height as well.

You may try to put imageView and textViews inside a relativeLayout and wrap textViews with imageViews height and then put that relativeLayout into row item. It will be nested, but i think still it is better than given exact size because that way it wouldn't be seen so good on some devices...

Comment: I forgot to write it but it's the width of the image view that changes, not the height.

Comment: Ok, so you want your imageView's width to be same with buttons width right? I think this would be much more easier to achieve with relativeLayout instead of tableLayout. Do you have to use tableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` and as u have given added `android:layout_weight="1"` to button add this line to other components also

Comment: I tried what you said and removed it but it's still the same, and about the layout weight it's there because from some reason match parent didn't work